# How to resolve this error "[DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value" in flutter?

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu

UI

[image]

in my code when  two parameters has in country dropdown

[image]

when selected India, then show Indian provinces. Also, when selected USA, then show USA provinces in the province dropdown the way, after selecting a province, and again when changing the country, then show an error.

[image]

How to resolve this error when like that scenario I want show warning message or when change country then province should be to change initial value.

code

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List<String> countries = ['USA', 'India'];
  List<String> indiaProvince = ['New Delhi', 'Bihar', 'Rajasthan'];
  List<String> usaProvince = ['Texas', 'Florida', 'California'];

  List<String> provinces = [];
  String? selectedCountry;
  String? selectedProvince;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Multi Level Dropdown'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        children: [
          // Country Dropdown
          DropdownButton<String>(
            hint: Text('Country'),
            value: selectedCountry,
            isExpanded: true,
            items: countries.map((String value) {
              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: value,
                child: Text(value),
              );
            }).toList(),
            onChanged: (country) {
              if (country == 'USA') {
                provinces = usaProvince;
              } else if (country == 'India') {
                provinces = indiaProvince;
              } else {
                provinces = [];
              }
              setState(() {
                selectedProvince != 'null';
                selectedCountry = country;
              });
            },
          ),
          // Country Dropdown Ends here

          // Province Dropdown
          DropdownButton<String>(
            hint: Text('Province'),
            value: selectedProvince,
            isExpanded: true,
            items: provinces.map((String value) {
              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: value,
                child: Text(value),
              );
            }).toList(),
            onChanged: (province) {
              setState(() {
                selectedProvince = province;
              });
            },
          ),
          // Province Dropdown Ends here
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you push `indiaProvince` and `usaProvince` into `provinces` every time country change, when you change country twice you will push two times `indiaProvince` into `provinces`, so change your country's onChanged to this:

```
onChanged: (country) {
  if (country == 'USA') {
    provinces = []; // <--- add this
    provinces = usaProvince;
  } else if (country == 'India') {
    provinces = []; // <--- add this
    provinces = indiaProvince;
  } else {
    provinces = [];
  }
  setState(() {
    selectedProvince = null; // <--- change this
    selectedCountry = country;
  });
},
```

Comment: still same error bro "There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: Bihar. 
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value
'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart':
Failed assertion: line 890 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
              items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
                return item.value == value;
              }).length == 1'"

Answer (score 1):

There is duplication of values in your Drop down, you need to exclude duplication using some way, I recommend using `toSet()`,instead of this part of your code:

```
items: countries.map((String value) {
              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: value,
                child: Text(value),
              );
```

Change it to this:

```
items: countries.toSet().toList().map((String value) {
              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: value,
                child: Text(value),
              );
```

then try running again

Comment: still same error bro "There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: California. 
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value
'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart':
Failed assertion: line 890 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
              items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
                return item.value == value;
              }).length == 1'"